# Как запарсить субобъект в GraphQL

Tags: golang, graphql

Собствено не парсится субобъект в поле объекта.

input:

```
   {
  Products(search: {limit: 1, filters: {single_amount: {gte: 5}}}) {
    data {
      product_name
      product_id
      sales_history {
        total_check
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Products": {
      "data": [
        {
          "product_id": 35,
          "product_name": "testpr",
          "sales_history": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

В коде описано вот так:

```
    gql.ProductType = graphql.NewObject(graphql.ObjectConfig{
    Name: "Product",
    Fields: graphql.Fields{
        "product_id": &graphql.Field{
            Type: graphql.Int,
        },
        "product_name": &graphql.Field{
            Type: graphql.String,
        },
        "sales_history": &graphql.Field{
            Type: gql.SalesHistoryType,
        },
    },
})

gql.SalesHistoryType = graphql.NewObject(graphql.ObjectConfig{
    Name: "sales_history",
    Fields: graphql.Fields{
        "total_check": &graphql.Field{
            Type: graphql.Float,
        },
    },
})
```

В Resolve возвращается интерфейс, внутри которого мапа. Выглядит вот так:

> map[data:[map[product_id:35 sales_history:map[total_check:671.20] product_name:testpr]]]

sales_history в отдельную мапу я сам пихаю. Без отдельной мапы в output`е напротив поля sales_history - null

Что я делаю не так?